# "Inside of" vs. "inside"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I guess this is an American usage.

When to use "inside of" versus "inside"?
Any example sentences would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 24):

In Standard English, *inside* is followed by *of* when it’s a noun, so you might say, for example, ‘I’ve never seen the inside of a prison.’ When it’s used as a preposition *of* is not required, so you can say ‘I’ve never been inside a prison.’ However, in non-standard speech, *of* is sometimes found even in that sort of construction.